# Как при помощи JS установить максимальное число символов, которое может быть введено пользователем в текстовое поле?

Tags: javascript, html

Использование атрибута `maxlength` не представляется возможным, т.к. оно неприменимо к полям с типом `number`. Предполагаю, что нужно использовать событие `oninput`: проверять количество символов, а потом обрезать строку.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант(если там только числа), можно указать максимальное значение числа:

```
max="999"
```

Или можно сделать функцию:

```
function limiter(field, size) {
 if (field.value.length > size) {
 field.value = field.value.substring(0, size);}
}
```

и добавить к слушателю для поля ввода:

```
onKeyUp="limiter(this,'20');"
```

Comment: менять полностью значение инпута на keyup не очень хорошо для пользователя

Comment: Я использую атрибут `max` но он работает только для стрелок или колёсика мыши. По-моему это недоработка браузеров, т.к. по идее `max` должен работать так же как и `maxlength`

Comment: @Grundy Да это вообще ужасно для пользователя, я вижу что ввод был осуществлён, а потом он волшебным образом исчезает.